# Enable gcc warning for literal char overflow

Tags: c, gcc, warnings

In gcc even with `-Wall` on, I get no warning for: `char x = 0xff;`

However with `-pedantic` I do.

Is there a way to turn on this warning, without using pedantic and getting other pedantic warnings?

Comment: Personally I would switch pedantic on and fix all the warnings. It's there for a reason!

Comment: try "signed char"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is another `FLAG`, if you don't wanna use `-pedantic/-Wpedantic`, you can try something like this:

```
error: conversion to ‘char’ alters ‘int’ constant value [-Werror=conversion]
 char x = 0xff;
          ^
```

if yes, then do:

```
gcc -Wconversion
```

Comment: It's weird that with `-pedantic`, gcc says `warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]`, but `-Woverflow` does nothing, but as you suggested, `-Wconversion` does seem to work in this case.

Comment: @G.Sliepen `but -Woverflow does nothing ` It happens because without optimisation the compiler doesn't do the necessary analysis to realise that in the multiplication expression it knows the values.

Comment: Yes I was looking for the warning of "overflow in implicit constant conversion".